# Angular factory $resource: 404 Not Found

Tags: angularjs, node.js, github

I'm new to Angular and I've been working on an Airline SPA which reads sample data from json file. The app works fine when running on nodejs (localhost:3000/airports), however it shows this error when I check it out on github: GET https://nlmazhari.github.io/airports  404 Not Found

this is my app.js:

```js
angular.module('airline', ['airlineServices'])
    .config(airlineRouter);

function airlineRouter ($routeProvider) {
 $routeProvider
  .when('/', {templateUrl: 'partials/destinations.html',
   controller: 'DestinationsCtrl'})
  .when('/airports/:airportCode', {
   templateUrl: 'partials/airport.html',
   controller: 'AirportCtrl'
  })
  .when('/flights', {
   templateUrl: 'partials/flights.html',
   controller: 'FlightsCtrl'})
  .when('/reservations', {
   templateUrl: 'partials/reservations.html',
   controller: 'ReservationsCtrl'});
}
```

these are my controllers:

```js
function AirportCtrl ($scope, $routeParams, Airport) {
 $scope.currentAirport = Airport.get({
  airportCode: $routeParams.airportCode
 });
}
```

```js
function DestinationsCtrl ($scope, Airport) {
  $scope.setActive('destinations');

  $scope.sidebarURL = 'partials/airport.html';
  $scope.currentAirport = null;

  $scope.setAirport = function (code) {
    $scope.currentAirport = Airport.get({airportCode: code});
  };

  $scope.airports = Airport.query();
}
```

and this is my services.js:

```js
angular.module('airlineServices', ['ngResource'])
 .factory('Airport', function  ($resource) {
  return $resource('/airports/:airportCode');
 })
 .factory('Flights', function  ($resource) {
  return $resource('/flights');
 })
 .factory('Reservations', function  ($resource) {
  return $resource('/reservations');
 });
```

can anybody guide me? why am I getting this error?

Comment: I think you are missing exact url of template/JSON file.Have a cross check on it.

Comment: thank u for your quick reply, I've checked where I added the path to my json files and it seems correct to me: var airports = require('./data/airports.json');
var flights = require('./data/flights.json'); can u please explain more clearly what seems wrong? I'd be thankful indeed

Comment: btw, the code is available in GitHub. I know I'm asking for a big favor but can u take a look?

Comment: Just now I got your code and gave a try. It's awesomely working fine. But,as you are hosting in Github,it should be static only. I mean without node.js. Please have a look into this document. https://pages.github.com/

Comment: Remove node code and rebuild it with Angular.Js.You must have index.html to bootstrap your website (In order to host in Github).

Comment: thanks to u dear friend, now I know what's wrong and I'm working on it. I actually don't know how to remove node code, so I tried to install harp(unsuccessful) and I'm digging in more about how to make it static or how to add node.js compatibility to the GitHub. thank u for clearing the way!